Sonarcloud code with Xcode Cloud 0 Lines of Code
I have an iOS project and want to analyze it with sonar. I have added a script to my Xcode Cloud so that the code is analyzed with every push.  Problem is that my develop branch in sonsarcloud overview is empty and also shows that there are 0 lines of code
Sonarcloud Dashboard
 My script: 
#!/bin/sh  
brew install sonar-scanner  

sonar-scanner \   
-Dsonar.projectKey="project-key” \   
-Dsonar.organization="organization” \   
-Dsonar.sources=. \   
-Dsonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io” \   
-Dsonar.login="$SONAR_TOKEN” \   
-Dsonar.branch.name="develop”

My code is in the main branch but when I do a merge from the develop branch to main there are still 0 lines of code.
Does anyone have any idea what I can change or improve?
